# Linear algebra 2 - inner products spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

I have a question in linear algebra 2, in the topic of inner product spaces:

$\text{Let V be an inner space product over field F (could be either}\>\mathbb{C}\>\text{or}\>\mathbb{R}\text{)}.\\
\text{Prove:}\>\forall u,v_1,\dots,v_m\in V,\forall \eta_1,\dots,\eta_m\in F:\left< u,\sum_{j=1}^{m}\eta_jv_j \right>=\sum_{j=1}^{m}\overline{\eta_j}\left<u,v_j\right>$

I started with this:

$\begin{array}{cccc}
\left\langle u,\sum_{j=1}^{m}\eta_{j}v_{j}\right\rangle  & = & \overline{\left\langle \sum_{j=1}^{m}\eta_{j}v_{j},u\right\rangle } & \because\text{hermiticity}\ \left\langle \ ,\ \right\rangle \\
 & = & \left\langle \sum_{j=1}^{m}\overline{\eta_{j}v_{j}},\overline{u}\right\rangle  & \because\text{properties of}\ \cdot_{\mathbb{C}},+_{\mathbb{C}}\\   
\end{array}$

I also thought of playing with things (properties of $<\>,\>>$, and properties of operations in $\mathbb{C}$), and I just didn't get a direction.

I'd appreciate a hint/a direction a lot.

Comment: You can't (in general, at least) enter the conjugate inside the inner product. So, the second equality is wrong. Try expanding the inner product and then use properties of conjugate. A nice _proof_ of this can proceed by induction, btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe
\begin{align}
\langle u, \eta_1v_1+\eta_2v_2\rangle 
=& \overline{\langle \eta_1v_1, u\rangle}+ \overline{\langle \eta_2v_2, u\rangle}\\
 =& \overline{\eta_1  \langle v_1, u\rangle}+ \overline{\eta_2  \langle v_2, 
u\rangle}\\
=&\ \bar \eta_1\langle u, v_1\rangle +\bar\eta_2\langle u, v_2\rangle.
\end{align}

Comment: Oh, that's very useful to me! I didn't think of that.
Thanks a lot. :)